# TortoiseSVN does not show context menu on files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-7-x64

A while ago I updated TortoiseSVN to 1.7.7 (64 bit) on my Windows 7 64 bit. Since that time, I don't have a SVN contextmenu on files. I do have the contextmenu when I rightclick on a folder, but sometimes I'd like to do a *diff* or *change* on a file and that is no longer possible.

I tried to reinstall and repair, but it didn't work. What should I try?

Comment: Have you updated your working copies, cause the format has changed from 1.6 to 1.7. May be you have working copies which are in old format...

Comment: Yes I did that a while ago. The 'SVN Upgrade working copy' command is no longer available in the menu so I guess that is fine now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I received an answer from the TortoiseSVN mailinglist. 
The reason there is no context menu on files is a registry permission problem. The fix is explained in the [TortoiseSVN FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#nofilemenus) but I completely overlooked it.

The solution is:

1. Go to registry editor using regedit.
2. Click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/​shellex/ContextMenuHandlers/TortoiseSVN
3. Observe error message box saying access is denied.
4. Right click on the key mentioned above, go to "Permissions"...
5. In the permission dialog, click on "Advanced"
6. Click on "Owner" tab, click on your account and click "Apply"
7. OK the dialog, click on "Add..."
8. Enter your account name in the text area and click "OK"
9. OK the permission dialog.
10. Click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/​shellex/ContextMenuH​andlers/TortoiseSVN
11. Check there is NO error message box.

Answer (score 2):

2 clues I have here:

- Double-check that you installed **64bit** version of TortiseSVN,
- Try restarting your machine.

Answer (score 2):

A more simpler approach...

The initial steps are kind of same as suggested by Jao and others...

1. Go to registry editor using regedit.
2. Click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/​shellex/ContextMenuHandlers/TortoiseSVN
3. After getting error, right click on TortoiseSVN (not on the KEY) and then "permissions"
4. Click "OK" for the dialog box that appears
5. Click "Advanced" -> Owners. Select your account.
6. Click "Apply" and then "OK".
7. Click "Add", type your account name, click "OK".
8. Select your account then and below, select "Full Control"
9. Click "Apply" and "OK" and you're good to go...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I down graded from a newer version of TortoiseSVN to an older version. In my case it wasn't related to the registry permissions.

To fix it I opened HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/​shellex/ContextMenuHandlers/TortoiseSVN and deleted the "Default" registry entry. Next I opened the same installer that I used to install TortoiseSVN. It detected that I had already installed it and gave me the option to repair or uninstall. I clicked on repair and it replaced the "Default" registry entry.

After the registry value was updated the context menu worked as intended.